# How to make this increment code works in laravel command file schedule

Tags: laravel

I'm updating those orders status "New" to "Cancel" using a command schuduler and running it every minute, the update function is working, but the problem is each time you update the New to Cancel, I have another condition to increment or add back the quantity of the ordered products back to the products stock

```
    $getNeworders = Order::with('products')
        ->where('order_status', '=' ,'New')
        ->whereDate('created_at' , '<' ,Carbon::now()->subMinutes(1440))->get();
    //1440minutes in 24hrs

    foreach($getNeworders as $try) {
        $gettheid= $try->id;
           Order::where(['id'=>$gettheid])->update(['order_status' =>'Cancelled']);

    }

    foreach($getNeworders as $increments){
    foreach($increments->product() as $incrementt)
        $idd= $incrementt->product_id;
        $qty= $incrementt->pivot()->quantity;

        Product::where(['id' => $idd])->decrement(['stock' => $qty]);
```

// the update is working fine, but the increment statement below is not working

Comment: by the way its increment, forgot to rename it

Answer (score 0):

There are missing curly brackets for `foreach($increments->product() as $incrementt)`. other thing is `increment/decrement` doesn't accept an array but a column name and a value.

so something like this:

```
foreach($getNeworders as $increments){
    foreach($increments->product() as $incrementt){
        $idd= $incrementt->product_id;
        $qty= $incrementt->pivot()->quantity;

        Product::where(['id' => $idd])->decrement('stock', $qty);
    }
}
```